# Ruby - ARGV.empty? ModuleName else code here end always returns ModuleName

Tags: ruby, module, argv

probably stupid question

I have some code:

```
if ARGV.empty?
  ModuleName
else
  #Awesome Code Here
end
```

But no matter what, the ModuleName module is always evaluated. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You should post a complete example so we can recreate it ourselves.  I highly doubt that the "if ARGV.empty?" Is malfunctioning.  Also say the actual output you are getting.

Comment: @DavidGrayson - OK - http://pastebin.com/MMeavYst

Comment: Don't put a link to your code in a comment. Put a snippet of your code that duplicates the problem into your original question. As is, *when* the link breaks your question will be of no value to future people looking for the answer to the same question. Also, by putting the code in the link, you are forcing anyone wanting to help you to go to that page. Instead, put everything they need to know in the question. Help them help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the module is actually evaluated when you require it, not because the `ModuleName` line is reached.

Example:

in a foo.rb file:

```
class Foo
   puts "foo"
end
```

And then in irb:

```
1.8.7 :001 > require 'foo'
foo
 => true
```

Comment: Now THAT makes sense...hmmm re-working the module appears to be in the works. thanks! EDIT = confirmed, I wrapped the module's actions in a self#method and all is right in the world

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can test the args your script is getting with something like this:

```
until ARGV.empty? do
  puts "Argument: '#{ARGV.shift}'"
end
```

Maybe you're actually passing it some args?